# Función is_dir() no me funciona con directorios que tienen espacios

Tags: php, php5

Estoy haciendo un funcion que me lista archivos y directorios con scan_dir() y luego me los separa en 2 arrays en función de si el elemento es un archivo o un directorio. el problema que tengo es que cuando se trata de un directorio, si tiene espacios en el nombre, me lo detecta como un archivo.

```
$dir = "application";
$scanned_files = scandir($dir);
$directories = array();
$files = array();

foreach($scanned_files as $index => $scanned_file){
    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$scanned_file)){
        array_push($directories, $scanned_file);
    } else {
        array_push($files, $scanned_file);
    }
}
```

Esto es un dump de $scanned_files:

```
 Array (
        [0] => $Recycle.Bin 
        [1] => Archivos de programa 
        [2] => Config.Msi 
        [3] => Documents and Settings 
        [4] => ESD 
        [5] => Intel
    )
```

Estoy leyendo que si le pongo a is_dir() la ruta entre comillas me lo hace bien, pero es que no soy yo el que pone la ruta si no el foreach() de las lista de archivos que saca la función scan_dir().

Alguna idea?

Comment: Prueba con `is_dir('\''.$dir.'/'.$scanned_file.'\'')`

Comment: Pues no, con eso directamente se lo toma toco como si fuesen archivos. Gracias

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente sin modificaciones: (Array de directorios) `array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "." [1]=> string(2) ".." [2]=> string(20) "Archivos de programa" [3]=> string(22) "Documents and Settings" }` Que versión de PHP usas?